# In C, how do I use both isalnum() and isxdigit() correctly?

Tags: c

For example,

```
char string[] = "0x4356abdc";

if (isalnum((int)string[0])) {
    printf("integer: %s\n", string);
} else if (isxdigit((int)string[0])){
    printf("hexadecimal integer: %s\n", string);
}
```

Right now, if I try to run this, it would always say `0x4356abdc` is an integer even though it's hex. What should I change so that the string will be recognized as hexadecimal?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to use `isalnum()` and all other functions from `<ctype.h>` with `char` values is to cast the argument as `(unsigned char)`:

```c
char string[] = "0x4356abdc";

if (isalnum((unsigned char)string[0])) {
    printf("integer: %s\n", string);
} else if (isxdigit((unsigned char)string[0])) {
    printf("hexadecimal integer: %s\n", string);
}
```

Yet your example seems to indicate that you are not so familiar with these functions: they take a single byte value and return whether this byte is an alphanumeric character code or one that represents a hexadecimal digit (`0` to `9`, `a` to `f` or `A` to `F`).

It you intend to check whether the C string represents the decimal or hexadecimal representation of an integer, you should use `strtol()`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int is_decimal_number(const char *s) {
    char *p;
    strtol(s, &p, 10);
    return (p != s && *p == '\0');
}

int is_hexadecimal_number(const char *s) {
    char *p;
    if (*s == '0' && (s[1] == 'x' || s[1] == 'X')) {
        strtol(s, &p, 16);
        return *p == '\0';
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char string[] = "0x4356abdc";

    if (is_decimal_number(string)) {
        printf("integer: %s\n", string);
    } else if (is_hexadecimal_number(string)) {
        printf("hexadecimal integer: %s\n", string);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried that but it's still saying string is an integer.

Comment: Haha yeah I'm quite new to these functions. I see what you're getting at here, if I'm understanding correctly and `string[] = 'ffff'`. This piece of code wouldn't return as hexadecimal?

Comment: Well `ffff` can be parsed as a hex number but in a C source file, it is an identifier. You must be more precise when specifying the problem. Another question: is `-1` considered an integer? or is it an operator `-` followed by an integer `1`?

Comment: Good point, for my program I would consider `-1` as an integer. Also, based off your code I made a slight change to mine and it seems to work now. At least for some hexadecimals.  
`if (isalnum((unsigned char)string[0]) && string[1] != 'x') {
    printf("integer: %s\n", string);
} else if (isxdigit((unsigned char)string[0])) {
    printf("hexadecimal integer: %s\n", string);
}`

Comment: @CaoTheNoob: actually, these tests will have many false positives.